# Fill in values in a column based on the values of another another column

Tags: sql

I need to geolocate some entities. I have a full set of postcodes but some entities are missing their geolocation, that is the longitude and latitude values.

I need to fill up the longitude and latitude values by using matching postcodes and their longitude and latitude values. This will result in an approximate geolocation for some providers, but still better than not having any values.

I am fairly new to SQL. I am attempting to resolve this first for latitude. I would think it could be solved by joining the table by itself and getting the values from equivalent postcodes with their latitude values. But I am not getting that right, as my result just duplicates the query.
I have created some sample data to make it easier to answer. How can I fill the nulls for postcodes 7010 and 6011 with the data available?

```
with [test_data] ([key], [Postcode],[latitude],[longitude]) as
     (
       select '1', '7010', '-41.27471' ,'173.28356'   union all 
       select '2', '8011' ,'-43.53299','172.63588'    union all
       select '3', '7010' , NULL      , NULL         union all
       select '4', '6011', '-41.29324', '174.78341' union all
       select '5', '2113','-37.08052'   ,'174.92238'union all
       select '6', '6011', NULL,    '174.78341'        

     )
    --select [key],[Postcode],[latitude],[longitude]
    --from   [test_data]

        SELECT *  FROM(
        SELECT [key],[Postcode],[latitude], [longitude]
        FROM [test_data]) AS s
        LEFT JOIN [test_data] j
        ON j.[key] = s.[key]
```

Comment: SQL Server <> MySQL. Please tag the RDBMS you are *really* using.#

Comment: So, if a row has no latitude or longitude, you'll look up other rows with the same postcode. You may find zero or one or even many entries. If there are many entries, do you care which entry's latitude or longitude you pick? Or will any for the same postcode do? Is this Microsoft SQL Server you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be much better if you downloaded a NZ post code data file and populated a separate lookup table, rather than depend on the presence of duplicate data in the same table.  (Google it - they are freely available.)

In any case, you would need to write an `UPDATE` statement that joins the target table to a reliable source, whether that be a dedicated post code table or the same source table. To only retrieve one post code row (in case there are multiple matches), you can use the `CROSS APPLY ( SELECT TOP 1 ... )` pattern.

The end result would be something like:

```
UPDATE T
SET
    latitude = P.latitude,
    longitude = P.longitude
FROM test_data T
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 S.latitude, S.longitude
    FROM SourceTable S
    WHERE S.Postcode = T.Postcode
    AND S.latitude IS NOT NULL
    AND S.longitude IS NOT NULL
    -- ORDER BY ??? (no order defined)
) P
WHERE (T.latitude IS NULL OR T.longitude IS NULL)
```

The above includes conditions to only update target rows having null latitude or longitude values, and to only select source post code rows having non-null values.

A `CROSS APPLY` is like an inner join to a subquery. If no matching post code row is found for a particular test_data row, no update will be applied to that row.

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/gl94ACdx) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

For the rows that miss the latitude and/or longitude you want to pick one from the rows of the same post code. Your problem: you get multiple matches, but you only need one.

The most appropriate value may be the average latitude / longitude for the post code. In a query you can use `COALESCE` to replace nulls with another value. In order to get the average over all rows with the same postcode, use `AVG OVER`.

```
select 
  key, postcode,
  coalesce(latitude, avg(latitude) over (partition by postcode)) as lat,
  coalesce(longitude, avg(longitude) over (partition by postcode)) as lon
from test_data;
```